# Path diagram for a second order factor model

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, amos

I want to fit a second order factor model to some data. Do I need to add an error term to the endogenous factor? I'm thinking about e10, here. I omitted it at first, but AMOS was surprised about that and questioned my model. What's the usual way to set up a two-level factor model?

[image: A path diagram from AMOS]

Comment: no experience with amos but i think the factor should have a variance specified / estimated (or set to one)

Comment: Yes. I think you're right. For a second-order factor model, you don't need the extra error term, but you need to specify that the variance is 1 or that one of the regression coefficients is 1.